# Jenkins jabber notification issue with certificate

Tags: notifications, xmpp, ssl-certificate, jenkins-plugins

My company has jabber server with certificate
I added this certificate to my keystore like this:

```
openssl s_client -connect ${HOST}:${PORT} >>host.crt
sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > host.crt
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias ${HOST} -file host.crt -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts
```

and still i cant get notification via jabber in jenkins

```
Jabber notifier plugin: Sending notification to: lana@jabber_host.com
Jabber notifier plugin: [ERROR] not connected. Cannot send message to 'lana@jabber_host.com'
```

Can any one help?

Logs:

```
INFO: Trying to connect to XMPP on jabber_host:5223/jabber_host
java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
   at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3003)
   at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
   at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1410)
   at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
   at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
   at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:325)
   at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:43)
   at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)


PM hudson.plugins.jabber.im.transport.JabberIMConnection connect
WARNING: service-unavailable(503)
   at org.jivesoftware.smack.NonSASLAuthentication.authenticate(NonSASLAuthentication.java:77)
   at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:212)
   at hudson.plugins.jabber.im.transport.JabberIMConnection.createConnection(JabberIMConnection.java:319)
   at hudson.plugins.jabber.im.transport.JabberIMConnection.connect(JabberIMConnection.java:162)
   at hudson.plugins.jabber.im.transport.JabberIMConnectionProvider.createConnection(JabberIMConne   ctionProvider.java:42)
   at hudson.plugins.im.IMConnectionProvider.create(IMConnectionProvider.java:65)
   at hudson.plugins.im.IMConnectionProvider.access$600(IMConnectionProvider.java:22)
   at hudson.plugins.im.IMConnectionProvider$ConnectorRunnable.run(IMConnectionProvider.java:183)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: You did (hard) restart Jenkins after installing the cert, right? The errors you are seeing are not related to SSL Certificate errors.

Comment: I also see that you use XMPP over legacy SSL (i.e. Port 5223). Try to set up a state of the art TLS XMPP connection (TLS on Port 5222).